# Why does Stack Overflow focus on programming questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Why does Stack Overflow focus on programming questions? It has so many sites listed on the footer of the site. It confuses me.

Comment: Stack Overflow was the first. The other Stack Exchange sites came later.

Comment: Stack Overflow is also the biggest

Comment: What *exactly* confuses you? Having separate sites for separate types of questions makes it more efficient and easier for people to focus on what they are currently interested in.

Comment: Or maybe you are wondering why _Meta_ Stack Overflow has so many questions about Stack Overflow? There is a plan to split it into a Meta for SO, and a general Meta for system-wide issues.

Comment: My edit made an assumption about what you meant with your second sentence. I was confident enough to make the edit, but I mention my edit just in case I was wrong.

Comment: Dude, I come from China too.Welcome to SE Community, unfortunately you will get a ton of down votes because...well, because you did not search and answer. Your question is very simple, SO is part of big SE family.

Comment: You did not say *why* you are confused and it is therefore difficult to respond.

Answer (score 5):

That is what Stack Overflow was made for. Programming questions.

It was created and when we saw it was good and the community started asking for sites that are not about programming, the other sites were created.

As time goes on, we add more and more sites in different topics (there is a whole process for the community to suggest new topics, gaining support for them, getting a site into private beta, then public beta then launching - not that all suggestions end up getting launched).

I suggest reading the [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/), starting for the oldest ones, including the podcasts.

Comment: *starting from the oldest ones, including the podcasts.* LOL, that's gold line.